# Why does my urllib.request return a http error 403?

Tags: python, web-scraping, error-code

i am attempting to make a program that downloads a series of product pictures from a site using python. The site stores its images under a certain url format https://www.sitename.com/XYZabcde where XYZ are three letters that represent the brand of the product and abcde are a series of numbers in between 00000 and 30000.
here is my code:

```
import urllib.request

def down(i, inp):
    full_path = 'images/image-{}.jpg'.format(i)
    url = "https://www.sitename.com/{}{}.jpg".format(inp,i)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

    print("saved")
    return None

inp = input("brand :" )

i = 20100

while i <= 20105:
    x = str(i)
    y = x.zfill(5)
    z = "https://www.sitename.com/{}{}.jpg".format(inp,y)
    print(z)
    down(y, inp)
    i += 1
```

With the code i have written i can successfully download a series of pictures from it which i know exist for example brand RVL from 20100 to 20105 will succesfully download those six pictures.
however when i broaden the while loop to include links i dont know will give me an image i get this error code :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/euan/Desktop/university/programming/Python/parser/test - Copy.py", line 20, in <module>
    down(y, inp)
  File "c:/Users/euan/Desktop/university/programming/Python/parser/test - Copy.py", line 6, in down
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)
  File "C:\Users\euan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\euan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\euan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\euan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\euan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\euan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\euan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

what can i do to check and avoid any url that would yield this result?

Comment: As the error message states, you (or your IP) has been forbidden access.  `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`   This can happen when a service running on the web server smells a bot (repeated hits, sniffing, etc.) so the IP is auto-blocked.

Comment: Do you need to authenticate? You should preferably use the `requests` package which is very competent at these sorts of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot as such know in advance which URLs you don't have access to, but you can surround the download with a try-except:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error

...

def down(i, inp):
    full_path = 'images/image-{}.jpg'.format(i)
    url = "https://www.sitename.com/{}{}.jpg".format(inp,i)
    try:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, full_path)
        print("saved")
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        print("failed:", e)


    return None
```

In that case it will just print e.g. "failed: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden" whenever a URL cannot be fetched, and the program will continue.

Comment: You're welcome, euan! Happy to hear that. Maybe you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer?

Comment: can you suggest a tutorial that explains the urllib.error ? I like to understand what my code is doing instead of just ripping it off of stackoverflow

Comment: I like that attitude. The `import urllib.error` imports the submodule "error" from the main module "urllib". In that module exists the exception class HTTPError, and we need that to tell Python that if an exception of type HTTPError happens in the try-except clause, it should go execute the code after the except clause. You can read more about try and except in many places, for instance https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html.

Comment: thanls again Jesper have a nice evening (if its evening where you are)

Comment: It is! Have a nice evening too, euan! 